# Intellij IDEA does not detect file changes

Tags: intellij-idea

I made some changes on .js file

for example: alert("msg");

This change was not recognized by Intellij when I click on 'Update' action "update classes and resources".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS is a static file that gets executed on clients side which is your browser, the problem could be anything from your IDE to your Machine being slow hence IDE execution is slow to your browser not refreshing to get changes or the location of JS file. Have you tried?

- Build > Rebuild Project
- Refresh your browser to get updates js file
- Machine not over heating or has enough memory

Without a specific error we can't really know for sure, try the above as from my experience IDE do get slow if the machine has insufficient memory.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your browser cache is storing outdated info, so updates to the static files are not reflected immediately on your browser.

Try pressing cmd + shift + R (mac),
or shift + f5 (windows).

This will perform a "hard reload".