# Intellij Compiled classes not reflecting changes to java files

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project written in Java. I was able to make changes to code and see its updates until the beginning of this week. For past 2 days  however, I am seeing a strange issue where no matter what changes I make to my java files, the compiled classes in target are not reflecting the changes and somehow seem to point to an older version of the compiled classes. I deleted target, invalidated cache, deleted .idea, changes the project folder to a different location and pulled again from git and nothing worked. I tried all comments listed at: [Intellij IDEA does not detect file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711167/intellij-idea-does-not-detect-file-changes)

I have Intellij version - 2022.1.3

Still no solution. I am not sure what is causing this issue. Any assistance in this would be greatly helpful. Thank you.

Comment: When you build your program via IntelliJ, does the 'Modified'-date of the .class-File(s) change? If no, does it change when using `mvn compile` instead?

Comment: Try re-install the IDE with all 3rd plugins disabled. Try the version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ If issue remains, file a report at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new with logs attached (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data action) and a sample project if possible or zipped `.idea` directory.